# Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2 Advanced Profiler not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-virtual-device

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2, and I want to use the Android Profiler tool.
So, I've created an AVD (Nexus 5X), ran my app, and I can see the timeline of CPU, Memory and Network, ok. Now, I can't use the "advanced profiling", (I have it enabled in my configuration). I've read the documentation [Enabling Advanced Profiling](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/android-profiler.html?utm_source=android-studio#advanced-profiling) and [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/android-profiler.html). And I figured, I had to enable ADB in my AVD (why isn't it enabled by default? I don't know), and when I enable it, my Android Studio shows "No connected devices". I've tried to close AS, AVD, open in order, reverse the order, among other things... What am I mising?